# winforms An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, exception

I am getting this error when trying to add multiple properties.

```
  public NewPropertyHelper(DataLayer.IAccrualRepository Repository) {
        this.SaveAction = Properties => {
            foreach (Property P in Properties)
            {
                Repository.Properties.AddObject(P);
                Repository.SaveChanges();
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather, the line

```
Repository.Properties.AddObject(P);
```

is attempting to add the object P to the current repository, and since you got it from a different repository you'd need to remove it (or detach it) from the other repository first.

EDIT: So I am assuming that somewhere in Repository, there is a wrapped DataContext (or maybe Repository inherits your DataContext.  When you get an object from a DataContext, the object is constantly references by a change tracker, which keeps track of what needs to be sent back to the database if you update that object.  Because you don't want to double-count any objects, EF prevents you from attaching that object to more than one data context at a time.  Before you can attach the object to a new data context, you need to *detach* it from the DataContext that is already tracking it.

To do that, you need to call the Detach method on the object and any objects that it references that are also tracked by EF.  A good example of how to do that is here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/linq-to-sql-detach.aspx

Comment: (DataLayer.IAccrualRepository) Repository is an interface that has an IObjectSet<Property> Properties. but how to remove it from repository as i dont have any direct connection to entity object.

Comment: You may not have the right abstraction on Repository then.  If you cannot get at the entity collection, you may need to create a new object and copy over all of it's properties.  Automapper is good for that: http://automapper.codeplex.com

Comment: Tried different way  foreach (Property P in Properties)
                {
                    AccrualTrackingEntities DataContext = new AccrualTrackingEntities();
                    DataContext.Detach(P);
                    DataContext.Properties.AddObject(P);
                    DataContext.SaveChanges();
                } but it says it does not exist in object state manager.

Comment: That won't work either, because the root problem is that the original context (in your function, the variable "this") is still holding a reference to the Property object.  Is it possible to reference the wrapped DataContext from within your current class?

Comment: What you mean by wrapped datacontext can you suggest some code for that in an answer form. You mean to say by using statement?

Comment: tried that created a new class with new context and wrapped with using statement. that also dint work

Comment: Based on the comment you posted you tried to detach P from a new data context.  Unfortunately that isn't the data context it is attached to.  it is (I think) attached to the data context wrapped by the class that you are in.

Comment: Found out the bug the error was not clear i had another object inside that list that was referring to different entity that is why that error was confusing.. Anyway Thanks a lot for the help.